# Android command-line tools: "cmdline-tools component is missing" error

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, java-8, android-sdk-tools

I'm encountering an issue with the Android command-line tools, specifically the error message

```
"cmdline-tools component is missing."
```

I'm trying to install the necessary components for Android development using the command

```
path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

as mentioned in the official documentation.

However, when I run the command, I receive the following error message:

```
"zsh: no such file or directory: path/to/sdkmanager."
```

I have verified that the path to the sdkmanager executable is correct and have tried various approaches, but the error persists.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Checked the correct path to the sdkmanager executable.
2. Verified the existence of the cmdline-tools component in the Android SDK installation directory.
3. Ensured that the path to the sdkmanager executable is properly formatted without any typographical errors.
4. Tried running the command from the correct directory but still encountered the same error.
5. I'm using [provide your operating system details], and I have already installed Java [provide your Java version details] for Android development.

i installed cmd-line tools.

[image]

[image]

and also when i tried `./sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
it says
[image]

here is the flutter doctor result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/mishalhaneef/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (6 days ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /Users/mishalhaneef/homebrew/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/34.0.1
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.92

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Any suggestions or insights on resolving this issue and successfully installing the Android command-line tools would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open `android studio`, open any existing project or create one. open it

then `tools`->`SDK manager`,

[image: like this]
in side bar select `android sdk` -> in tab bar select `sdk tools` -> in the list `select Android SDK Command-line Tools`.

[image: like this]

then apply and click ok it will download.

then try flutter doctor.

if problem still exist try

```
flutter config --android-sdk YOUR_PATH_FOR_SDK
```

YOUR_PATH_FOR_SDK can be found `tools->SDK manager->android sdk->Android sdk location`

Comment: i already did that, i updated my question . still not working

Comment: can you share **flutter doctor**  log

Comment: i edited and updated

Comment: run 'flutter config --android-sdk YOUR_PATH_FOR_SDK'

YOUR_PATH_FOR_SDK can be found in  tools->SDK manager->android sdk->Android sdk location.

then run 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' and accept all by typing "Y"

Comment: you are welcome @mishalhaneef updated my answer . in case any one face this issue

Answer (score -1):

1. `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

```
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 5 more
```

2. Install Android SDK Command-line Tools in Android Studio:

Preferences → Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK → SDK Tools → Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)

Comment: i already told you that i tried this, and already downloaded the sdk tools, you can see the screenshots